# Regular Expression for changing String

Tags: regex

I want to match a String with a regular expression in order to capture some groups of characters. 
The String has the following format:

```
Some Error occured. Exception on row 0: execution of BeforeDelete cannot delete object  // I want to capture this part

(Namespace)  // This
             // Part
: []         // is optional
             // and redundant
(Namespace)  // for me

Class.Namespace.ClassName.MethodName: line 18, column 1  // This
Class.Namespace.ClassName.MethodName: line 24, column 1  // part
Class.Namespace.ClassName.MethodName: line 7, column 1   // i want 
Trigger.Namespace.TriggerName: line 4, column 1          // to capture

Debug Log:                                              // This part
32.0                                                    // is also
12:17:50.037 (37913230)|EXECUTION_STARTED               // optional
12:17:50.037 (37955457)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]    // and
12:17:50.038 (38147219)|VF_DESERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_BEGIN  // redundant
```

It consists out of 2 mandatory and 2 optional groups

1. MANDATORY: Group of characters including whitespaces i want to capture
2. OPTIONAL: additional characters including whitespace and multiline I dont want to capture
3. MANDATORY: characters with whitespace and possible multiline I want to capture. Starts always with 'Class.' or 'Trigger.'
4. OPTIONAL: additional characters including whitespace and multiline I don want to capture, starts always with 'Debug Log:'

I am using this Regex:

```
(.+)(?:[\s\S]*)(Class\.[\s\S]+|Trigger\.[\s\S]+)[\s]*
```

The Regex should take into account that group 2 and 4 may be missing on other target strings than this example. Keep in mind that the content of the optional groups could vary.

Does anyone have an idea how to improve this?

Thank you

Comment: How would you like it improved?

Comment: I don't understand which part of the string parts 1 and 2 are supposed to refer to.

Comment: I am sorry i had a redundant piece of Regex in it which has nothing to do with the question. I updated the Regex example.

Comment: I want the regex to take into account that some parts of the string are optional ( by which I mean its possible they occur on other target strings or not).

Comment: @RobertMéndez I understand that some parts are optional. WHICH PARTS? "Additional characters including whitespace and multiline I dont want to capture" doesn't tell me enough

Comment: @DevonParsons I added comments to the Target String. Is this enough information? PS: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

This expression:

```
^(.+?)\(.+?((?:Class\.|Trigger\.).+(?=(?:Class\.|Trigger\.|Debug)))+
```

along with `RegexOptions.Singleline` (`.` character matches line breaks) warrants the following two capture groups, based on your example data:

1:

> Some Error occured. Exception on row 0: execution of BeforeDelete cannot delete object

2:

> Class.Namespace.ClassName.MethodName: line 18, column 1
>   Class.Namespace.ClassName.MethodName: line 24, column 1
>   Class.Namespace.ClassName.MethodName: line 7, column 1
>   Trigger.Namespace.TriggerName: line 4, column 1

Is this what you're looking for?

---

Edit: If the first capture is strictly on the first line, you can anchor on a line break instead:

```
^(.+?)\r\n.+?((?:Class\.|Trigger\.).+(?=(?:Class\.|Trigger\.|Debug)))+
```

Comment: No because the first optional group can change in appearance. It doesn't always start with '(' it can start with all kind of characters

Comment: The second optional group however does either start with 'Debug Log' or is missing completely

Comment: @RobertMéndez See my edit. If what you want to capture is always on the first line (there are no line breaks) then you can anchor on a line break instead of an open parenthesis `(`.